# sflow top talker support

Tags: cisco, switch, netflow, sflow

I have nexus `9300` switch and i have configured `sflow` and i want to find out top-talker IP from command line but i am not seeing any command.

I have Cisco ASR1k and i have configured `netflow` and i can see top-talker  there with following command

`show flow monitor netflow-monitor cache sort counter bytes top 10`

Question: does sflow support top-talk like netflow?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

sFlow and NetFlow differ in a fundamental way:

1. With NetFlow the switch is responsible for building a flow cache that is used to generate and export NetFlow records. In addition, the "show flow" commands can be used to query the cache on the switch.
2. sFlow reduces the monitoring resources needed on the switch by moving the flow cache from the switch to the external sFlow collector. You must have an sFlow collector if you want to see the top talkers with sFlow.

The article, [Cisco adds sFlow support](https://blog.sflow.com/2012/08/cisco-adds-sflow-support.html), describes additional differences.

Comment: Does that mean I can't see top top talker from switch command line ? I have to do export and the use whatever tool to find top talker, is that right?

Comment: Yes. You need to export sFlow to an external tool to find top talkers. sFlowTrend is a free tool.